# How do I adjust the actual font sizes in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I like having as much stuff on the screen at once as I can.  But as a consequence of getting on in years, small font sizes are starting to become a problem.  Internet Explorer has the ability to increase the font size of text in webpages (those pages that don't set the font size explicitly).  On the main menu, it is View | Text Size.  The choices are: Smallest, Smaller, Medium, Larger, Largest.

Medium is on many web pages just a tad too small to me.  But if I go to Larger the font size is way too big.

My question is, is there a way to set these text size jumps differently from what they seem to be?

Comment: I have never found a way to set the base font size used by IE; you might want to think about switching to Chrome or FireFox, both of which allow you to specify the base font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the jumps using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + mousewheel are smaller than the ones from the view menu. Not used IE in a while though, so it might have changed.

Comment: This works nicely, thanks! Although it causes the page to go to horizontal scrollbars as size goes up.  But is there a way to change settings, though?

Comment: I'd rather give no answer than a wrong one, so I'll leave it to someone else -- I don't know.

Comment: In addition to Zooming, you can look under "View" -> "Text Size" -> "Largest". This will change the text size but everything else will remain the same size, so scrollbars are less likely too appear. You may need to press "alt" when in IE to get the Edit menu to appear.

Comment: @vcsjones - That was what he did in the OP.